# Jquery check boxes to populate list

Tags: jquery, checkbox, filter

I am attempting to populate a list of links depeding on what checkbox options are checked by a user. You can see what I have done so far here to give you an idea of what I am doing
http://dev.perfectdaycanada.com/filter  - the problem I am having is that I cant seem to get the checkboxes to populate links if only a county or a farm is selected. So at the moment one of the first set of checkboxes must be selected for the subsequent ones to work. Ideally any checkboxes ckecked should populate the list of links.

Any help would be much appretiated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what type of functionality are you trying to achieve? What kind of results do you want when checks clicked, sort of a before and after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code just add this link at the top of your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').find(':input.type_check:first').attr({'checked':'checked'});

   ....
});
```

Comment: here .type_check is your first section checkboxes class name

Comment: and :first will select the only first checkbox